# Add private pem key to AWS Task Definition

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS CloudFront distribution with an ssh key restrict behavior, I would like to sign the urls that being distributed, unfortunately in Kotlin / Java the AWS SDK needs the ssh private key as a File, and the environment variables in AWS Task Definition only accepts text.

Is there a workaround for my private key to reach my AWS Task Definition?

I tried looking on the internet but all of the answer will give you answer for local environment which is put the file path inside a File class, I can not do that in a actual deployment as I will need to upload the private key in my docker image to accomplish it which defeats the purpose of public-private key

I'm expecting a workaround where my private key will reach my image externally.

Answer (score 1):

I satisfy my use case to convert the String to a PrivateKey

I removed both -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- in my private key

```
private fun signUrl(domain: String, private: String, public: String, key: String): String {
val amazonByte = com.amazonaws.util.Base64.decode(private)
val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(amazonByte)
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
val privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec)
return CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy("https://$domain/$key", public, privateKey, getExpiration())}
```